# how to add parameters to html email template

Tags: emails, theming

I have a working html email using modules: *Mail System, HTML Mail, SMTP Authentication Support.*

And I want to include some parameters/variables in the html email template file:

```
htmlmail--htmlmail.tpl.php
```

some variables include: `$base_path` etc. from `page.tpl.php` variables

From what I've read from the Internet, you may use "hooking" and I haven't yet hooked variables so far for my template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the **yourtheme_preprocess_htmlmail()** function for **htmlmail** email template in put in the **template.php** file of your current theme. I will give an example.

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_htmlmail(&$variables) {
  switch($variables['key']){
    case 'password-reset':
     $variables['var1'] = t('SAMPLE TEXT');
     break;
    case 'register-no-approval-required':
     $variables['var1'] = t('SAMPLE TEXT');
     break;        
    break;
   }
   $variables['heading'] = t('Heading text');
   $variables['copyright'] = t('Copyright text.');
 }
```

In this example. I created some customized variables base on the mailkey and defined some others like **heading**, **copyright**

Comment: i've encounter this hook but it seems to me it didn't work, i can't access variables like heading in the htmlmail template file, here is the output of the $variables object in the email for this bin(haha, disregard the infos): http://phpbin.net/8bYMvJHO by the way, i used another class: HTMLMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem, would it matter the hook function name?

Comment: For the email template, i think you should copy the **htmlmail.tpl.php** from **htmlmail module**. I think The **htmlmail--htmlmail.tpl.php** just uses for testing HTMLMailSystem

Comment: i see, thanks for this, i just only tried using send test email and the preprocess hook(mytheme_preprocess_htmlmail) doesn't even called/invoked so variables object isn't manipulated/add, why is this?

Comment: and sorry I can't upvode you now since I just started to create this account, soon...

Comment: I checked already. The preprocess_htmlmail function didn't apply for sending test email. You can test that by go to **admin/config/people/accounts**, enable **Notify new user when account created by admin.** and create new account to receive a email. Remember set the **HTMLMailSystem__SmtpMailSystem** value for the **Site-wide default MailSystemInterface class** in **Mail System**